# Two Spring Boot projects both with @SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a data project and UI project. Both projects are Spring Boot applications. Both projects have the same root package (com.myorg) with a main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

Data project's main class is:

```
package com.myorg;
@SpringBootApplication
public class DataApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DataApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The UI project's main class is:

```
package com.myorg;
@SpringBootApplication
public class UiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UiApplication .class, args);
    }

}
```

The UI project depends on the data project via the following Gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.myorg:data:1.0')
}
```

If I run the UI application, it runs without issue. However, if I run an integration test within the UI application such as follows:

```
package com.myorg
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UiIntTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

The following initialization error occurs:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found multiple @SpringBootConfiguration annotated classes`

In the data project's main class, if I replace `@SpringBootApplication` with

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({ "com.myorg" })
```

I get the following initialization error when trying to run its integration tests:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
```

For example, if I try to run:

```
package com.myorg
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DataIntTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

How can I properly configure the data and UI projects?

Comment: show more codes. add your package structure and hierarchy

Comment: @Olayinka - I have added more code and package structure detail. Please let me know if I'm still missing some relevant details.

Comment: You can't have two springapplication annotations in the same package

Comment: For the record, you *can* have 2 SpringBootApplication in the same package. Whether it is a good idea is another story. When you have more than one, you need to specify the `main-class` property in the `pom.xml`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to specify which Spring Boot Main class to use along with `@SpringBootTest`:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = YourUiSpringBootApp.class)
```

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't have two SpringApplication annotations in the same package.

Package one.

```
twoapps.one;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {One.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class One extends SpringApplication {
}
```

Package two.

```
twoapps.two;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {Two.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Two extends SpringApplication {

}
```

Root package and launcher

```
package twoapps;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import twoapps.one.One;
import twoapps.two.Two;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Thread(() -> SpringApplication.run(One.class, args(args, "--spring.profiles.active=one"))).start();
        new Thread(() -> SpringApplication.run(Two.class, args(args, "--spring.profiles.active=two"))).start();
    }

    private static String[] args(String[] args, String s) {
        List<String> collect = Arrays.stream(args).collect(Collectors.toList());
        collect.add(s);
        String[] strings = collect.toArray(new String[]{});
        return strings;
    }
}
```

This is a terrible idea. please don't do it. It is much better to have two different projects and a common project.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was concerned about my approach but not sure how to handle with integration testing. Let's suppose the common project contains Spring repositories, various Spring beans that need to be wired up, and a properties file (containing db connection info, etc.) I currently use `@SpringBootApplication` in conjunction with `@SpringBootTest` to wire things up and set properties in a Spring Boot specific way for my integration tests. But how would I configure my application for integration testing without it being defined as a SpringBootApplication?

Comment: @James You can specify anything as your SpringBootApplication for testing. What is important is the base package that is scanned by spring. If you have conflicting annotations in a package tree, then the context won't start. `@SpringBootTest(classes = {})`. The test will scan its package (and children) if you don't specify any class(es) otherwise it will scan the package of the class(es) you specify.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand. So, it's OK for the common project to have its own `@SpringBootApplication` class, but it should reside in a different package than the dependent project's (e.g. UI project's) `@SpringBootApplication` class. That being said, the UI project will need to wire up common project's components. Correct? So, the UI project's `@SpringBootApplication` class needs to be in a package that is a parent to all of the common project class components or specify `scanBasePackages` to include the common project's base packages. Do I have this right?

Comment: Is your last sentence referring to your entire post? Like "the setup above is a terrible idea, please don't do it?" Or are you saying "do it with two classes like my first two blockquotes, not one like my final blockquote"?