# springboot project with multiple module and multiple main class -unit test failing

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to write unit test cases for an existing application with multiple module having main classes in each of them. There are more than one class having \@SpringBootApplication. I have written a simple test case which is failing with following error. How can I continue with my test case for one of them.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found multiple
>   @SpringBootConfiguration annotated classes [Generic bean: class
>   [com.marketshare.ReportingMainClass]; scope=; abstract=false;
>   lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null;
>   defined in file [C:\My
>   Data\workspace\services2\microservices\Reporting-Microservice\build\classes\java\main\com\marketshare\ReportingMainClass.class],
>   Generic bean: class [com.marketshare.SharedMain]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null;
>   defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/C:/My%20Data/workspace/services2/microservices/Shared-Module/build/libs/Shared-Module-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/marketshare/SharedMain.class]]
>         at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
>         at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootConfigurationFinder.scanPackage(SpringBootConfigurationFinder.java:69)
>         at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootConfigurationFinder.findFromPackage(SpringBootConfigurationFinder.java:59)
>         at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootConfigurationFinder.findFromClass(SpringBootConfigurationFinder.java:52)

Here is the code snippet

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(CustomReportController.class)
public class CustomReportControllerTest {

}
```

I just want to unit test my controller. BTW I am new to spring world.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Spring Boot projects both with @SpringBootApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730099/two-spring-boot-projects-both-with-springbootapplication)

Comment: Going through different doc I came to know that @WebMvcTest is good enough to test a controller in isolation. The link that you have specified is using \@SpringBootTest annotation and loads the full context as per my understanding. For unit testing of my controller and make it fast I just want to test this controller.

Answer (score 1):

The @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) will load the spring context. To test just the controller you can use

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustomReportControllerTest {

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vitor. I tried that and it worked. It is fast also. Then what is the difference between \@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)  and the other two I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple approach, you can creatae a new Spring Boot Application, let's say `TestApplication` under your `test` source folder, just like

src\test\java\com\example\TestApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("......").
@EnableAsync
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and add your package into the `@ComponentScan`, you can get all the spring boot capacities and only applicable to the test propose.

Answer (score 0):

Add @SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
Use these annotations on the test class and Autowire MockMvc and then you can use mockMvc.perform to test Controller methods